# How to give discounts to certain people or business people in iOS

Tags: iphone, sdk, discounts

I have one app and i need to provide some kind of discounts to other people. Like if i show a demo version to some clients and if they like it, they are ready to buy the paid  version however they need discount in paid version. Its some kind of sales app, in which a sales person will show a demo to some clients or vendors, if they like it, they might ask for paid version with some discounts for certain devices. Is it possible to give discounts in this way. What about using B2B in this kind of module.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do that.

There are two methods of converting demo application to full version.

In demo version you can lock some functionalities and then in paid you can simply unlock those.

So to give a discount you can use UUID or Mac-address of device to track the target device and then can show them a particular product based on the discount category.

As you know that apple had changed his policy and the applications using UUID are not getting approved so you can better use the mac address of device to identify the user.